# @Annotation Mapping in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, routes

Is there anyway to map routes without `conf/routes` file in `play framework`. like `@HttpRequest(url="/someurl")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box. See this issue:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1139

But, there are some reasons to not do it and I suggest you to don't fight the framework. If Play uses `/conf/routes`, stick to it because everything will evolve around this way of doing things. Per instance, by using a custom router that supports annotations, you will probably give up:

1. Reverse routing for your views and other controllers
2. Default controllers offered by the framework (`controllers.Assets`) or by module creators
3. Possible performance loss if your solution is not as fast as the default one.

Not sure if it is worth.

Comment: well understand. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to have your routing embedded in your controller rather than in a separate config file play 2.5 actually now supports this through its String Interpolating Routing DSL (a mouthful i know).

here's the docs for it:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSirdRouter